# virtual host *:80 is not working

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am trying to set up a proxy redirection for tomcats.

I have a webserver apache24 listening on port 80 and it is doing proxy to tomcat ajp port. I have done the below configuration and it is working fine.

```
<Proxy *>
 Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass       /core ajp://localhost:8009/test
ProxyPassReverse  /core ajp://localhost:8009/test
ProxyPass       / ajp://localhost:9009/
ProxyPassReverse   /  ajp://localhost:9009/
```

Now I try to do the virtual host configuration it stops working. I have done this configuration in some other servers and it is working fine with out any issues. I am not able to figure out what is happening. When I configure the virtual host it is redirecting to apache index page. I am using apache 2.4, I do not have any other configuration files in conf.d folder. Ideally as i have configured for *:80 all host name and ip address should enter this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Proxy *>
 Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPass       /core ajp://localhost:8009/test
ProxyPassReverse  /core ajp://localhost:8009/test
ProxyPass       / ajp://localhost:9009/
ProxyPassReverse   /  ajp://localhost:9009/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any errors in apache logs ? don't forget to put the LogLevel to debug in apache2.conf